# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'addVar'

Tags: python, gurobi

I am stuck on this error:

`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'addVar'`

This is a part of my code

```
from gurobipy import*
m = ()
#model data
import xlrd
file_location = "C:/Users/Mohamed/Desktop/Service.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("servicetime")
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
Trucks=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]
Slots=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Areas=[1,2,3,4,5]
U=[1,2]
R=[1]
tin=[0.1667,0.3333,0.1667,0.3333,0.25]
tout=[0.1667,0.3333,0.1667,0.3333,0.25]
T=[0.75]
x,g,tin,tout,ta1a2,t,U,P,V,R={},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}
#define variables
for n in Trucks:
    g[n]=m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name="g[%s]"%(n))
```

Comment: `m = ()` you've defined a tuple here. `tuples` have nothing called `addVar`. You're expecting `m` to be something else. But it's not clear from the code you posted what `m` needs to be

Comment: this means the model name 
m=Model()

Answer (score 1):

You need a Gurobi Model object: `m = Model()`. Also, it is easier if you use `Model.addVars()`, as in:

```
g = m.addVars(Trucks, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="g")
```

Comment: (TypeError: 'TempConstr' object is not iterable )

Seemingly, I have a new error. what can I do ?